# How to create a bootable USB Drive that will boot on BOTH an Intel Mac and a PC

Tags: usb, disk-format, bootable-disk

I recently created a bootable USB Thumb Drive containing a Linux Live Distro. I created it on a PC running Windows and tested it successfully on the same PC.

Now I want to run the same Linux OS on my Mac with an Apple T2 Security Chip, using the same Thumb drive.

I booted into Recovery mode to allow booting from an external drive.

After restarting and holding the `option` key, I got a choice of "Macintosh HD" or "EFI Boot". I chose "EFI Boot".

[image]

After what looked like a Mac loading bar, I finally got the following message: "Unable to verify startup disk."

[image]

My question is: How can I create a bootable Linux USB drive (read-only, I don't need to persist anything to the drive) that will reliably let me boot it both on my Mac and a PC device ? Do I need a specific Disk Format ? Do I need to create it with a specific software?

Comment: So you created a bootable Linux drive on your PC to boot that PC. What makes you think that you don't have to do the same thing on the Mac: create the boot drive on the Mac? Generally speaking you can't install Windows or Linux on one computer and then expect it to run on another as there are differences in hardware and driver requirements. It is unlikely you can do this unless the Mac and Windows device are the same computer.

Comment: Even if you get to boot them, it can be troublesome because different hardwares and drivers may cause issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my Mac's Startup Security Utility, I had selecte "Allow booting from external media", but not "No Security" from the section above called "Secure Boot". Once I had selected "No Security" as well, I was able to boot from by thumb drive (FAT32).

[image]